# How do you center align in CSS with the style tag?

Tags: html, css

How do I align this to the center of the page?
http://jsfiddle.net/WH7Kf/39/

```
<div id="lower" style="position:fixed; width:95%; height:5%; background-color:green; ">
```

Comment: Here - http://jsfiddle.net/3Gf9b/

Comment: Many more question on stack

Comment: Align horizontally only I assume?

Comment: There are several questions on this site on vertically aligning divs, but for a quick and dirty solution, try `<div id="lower" style="position:fixed; width:95%; height:5%; background-color:green; right:2.5%; top: 47.5%">`

Comment: it's not a duplicate, since it doesn't do anything in JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WH7Kf/66/

Comment: The answers at the duplicate absolutely do work. You just can't *tell* because your fiddle in your above comment sets no background color, and is probably being viewed in a viewport less than 800px wide. [See this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PmVha/)

Comment: How do I delete it, or whatever I need to do now to work on chipping away my ban?

Comment: Deleting questions will make your ban *worse*, not better.

Comment: that's what I did over the time when I started accidentally :'(  how do I undelete old questions that were from 30+ days ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either do it this way:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

Inside your style or you can also use the `position`ing property as well:

```
position:absolute;
top:0%;
left:50%
```

There isn't a set way to center something, but these are ways that it can be done. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can align block-level elements using `margin:0 auto;`:

```
<div id="lower" style="margin:0 auto; width:95%; height:5%; background-color:green; ">
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WH7Kf/40/)

This works because you define the margin on the right and left side to be determined automatically, so it'll be in the very middle of the page.

Comment: @downvoter, mind explaining why you downvoted this answer?

Comment: I don't understand why this answer has been down-voted, this is what the OP asked.

Comment: What if he wants the div fixed positioned?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

http://jsfiddle.net/WH7Kf/41/

```
#lower {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:95%;
    height:5%;
    background:green;
    margin:auto;
}
```

If you want to make the div get literary centered both vertical and horizontal, add `top:0;` and `bottom:0;`